# SFMC: How to select multiple checkboxes based on single checkbox selection & display popup if opt out checkbox is selected?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a requirement where I created Preference page using amp script which updates certain field on Contact records based on Selection on Marketing Cloud "Cloud Page" that I designed using AMP script.

I am new to AMPScript and not completely aware of all syntaxes yet. So not aware of best practices.

There are 2 things which I want to achieve here.

1. When user select Optout checkbox, I want to show popup window there along with message and two button Yes and No. If User select Yes then it should save the information and update Email out out field on Contact and there is Subscriber Lists option where if User's email address match then it should automatically Subscribe from the lists in Marketing Cloud. If user Opt In again then it should again Subscribe user's email.If select No then it should go back to previous page. There is a code from line 10 to 67 where sample Popup message should display when page loads but its not working at all.
2. On line 162 there is an Opt in checkbox where if I select it then other 2 checkboxes Newsletter and Promotion Checkboxes should be select automatically. I have newsletter and promotion field on Contact which is getting updated but no opt in field.

How can I automatically check  both newsletter and promotion checkbox if Opt in is check? If User select opt in and then uncheck any of the checkbox of either newspaper or promotions, Main checkbox optin should be uncheck.

How can I display popup window and update subscriber list?

For 1st requirement, I tried to search for popup window in amp script but I could not fetch the popup window on checkbox on click event and no idea about how to update the Subscriber lists?

For 2nd Requirement, I did try to use IIf statement but it is somehow not reading Optin value that I selected and hence could not automatically check other 2 checkboxes.

**Below is the AMPScript code:**

```
        <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdn.ampproject.org">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=2,user-scalable=yes">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org">

  <title>Preference Center</title>

  <link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js">
  <script custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" async></script>
  <style amp-boilerplate>
        body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}
    </style>
  </noscript>
  
  <style amp-custom>
    @keyframes amp-pop-up-delay {
      to {
        visibility:visible
      }
    }
    body #amp-popup.amp-active{ 
      background:rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.83);
      border-color:#242323b3;
      z-index:10000;
      height:-webkit-fill-available;
      height:-moz-fill-available;
      top:0;
      visibility:hidden;
      animation:0s linear 3s forwards amp-pop-up-delay; /* here is the delay settings */
    }
    
    .popup {
      position:fixed;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
      width:800px;
      margin:0 auto;
      width:90%;
      padding:20px;
      height:90vh;
    }
    .popup__wrapp { 
      position:relative;
      background:#fff;
      box-shadow:0px 0px 60px 0px #d0d0d0;
      border-radius:10px;
      text-align:center;
      padding:40px;
      overflow-y:auto;
      max-height:90vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="background-color: transparent; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 25px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">

<script runat="server">   
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

   try {
</script>  
%%[

SET @optIn = RequestParameter("OptIntoallcommunication") 

output(concat("<br>variable: ", @optIn))
   ]%% 
%%[
var @email, @ContactId, @LeadId,@fistname, @lastname 
SET @email = RequestParameter('emailid')
SET @firstname=  RequestParameter('firstname')
SET @lastname=  RequestParameter('lastname')

  /*If  email is not mapped with lead so check with contact */
  SET @contactRow = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
        "Contact","Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Promotions__c,HasOptedOutOfEmail",
      "Email", "=", @email, "FirstName", "=", @firstname, "LastName", "=", @lastname
        ) 
   

       IF RowCount(@contactRow) > 0 THEN
       SET @row                             = row(@contactRow,1)
       SET @FirstName                       = field(@row,"FirstName")
       SET @LastName                        = field(@row,"LastName")
       SET @Email                           = field(@row,"Email")
       SET @Promotions                      = field(@row,"Promotions__c")
       SET @HasOptedOutOfEmail              = field(@row,"HasOptedOutOfEmail")
       SET @Surveys                     = field(@row,"Exclude_From_Emails__c")
   
       SET @contactId                       = field(@row,"Id")

       

        IF @Newsletters == true THEN SET @Newschk = "checked" ENDIF
        IF @Promotions == true THEN SET @Promotionschk = "checked" ENDIF
       
        IF @HasOptedOutOfEmail     == true THEN SET @HasOptedOutOfEmailschk = "checked" ENDIF  

  

    ]%%


%%[
 

 IF  RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RowCount(@contactRow) > 0 THEN





     if not Empty(@preferences) then
     SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", @contactId,
          "News__c", Iif(RequestParameter("newsletters") == "on", "true","false"),
          "Promotions__c", Iif(RequestParameter("promotions") == "on", "true", "false"),
          "HasOptedOutOfEmail", Iif(RequestParameter("optoutofall") == "on", "true", "false")
      ) 
     else
    SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", @contactId,
          "News__c", Iif(RequestParameter("newsletters") == "on", "true","false"),
          "Promotions__c", Iif(RequestParameter("promotions") == "on", "true", "false")
          "HasOptedOutOfEmail", Iif(RequestParameter("optoutofall") == "on", "true", "false"),
          "Email_News__c", Iif(RequestParameter("optoutofall") == "on", "false", "true")

     endif 

      endif
  

]%%




<script runat="server">    } catch(e) { Variable.SetValue("@error","Record doesn't exist in salesforce") }
</script><span>%%=v(@error)=%%</span>   


&nbsp;<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <label><b>Email: </b></label><input type="text" name="email" class="outText" value="%%=v(@email)=%%" readonly><br>
<br><br>



<label class="container"><b>Opt In to all communication</b> - 
Please check this option to select all below eight interest areas
  <input type="checkbox" id="OptIntoallcommunication" name="OptIntoallcommunication" %%=v(@optInChk)=%%>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container"><b>Newsletters</b>
  <input type="checkbox" id="newsletters" name="newsletters" %%=v(@Newschk)=%%>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>


<label class="container"><b>Special Offers</b> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="promotions" name="promotions" %%=v(@Promotionschk)=%%>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Opt out of all communication.
  <input type="checkbox"  id="optoutofall" name="optoutofall" %%=v(@HasOptedOutOfEmailschk)=%%>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br> 
<br>

 <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
        <input type="submit" style="background-color:#d52b1e;color:white; width:200px;border-radius: 30px;border:none; height:48px; font-weight: bold" value="SUBMIT"> 
  

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


 <style class="main_style">
.layout-canvas-g {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.layout-canvas-g > .header,
.layout-canvas-g > .section,
.layout-canvas-g > .footer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.layout-canvas-g > .section {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.layout-canvas-g > .section > .columns {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobile-hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .responsive-td {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
.layout-canvas-g > .section > .columns {
  width: 100%;
}

.outText{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
}


select {
  margin: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
}

select::-ms-expand { 
    display: none; /* remove default arrow on ie10 and ie11 */
}

@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    select {
        background:none\9;
        padding: 5px\9;
    } 
}


.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 6px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>





<div class="layout layout-canvas-g">
 <div class="section">
  <div class="columns col1">
   <div data-type="slot" data-key="col1" data-label="Drop blocks or content here"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

  </form>


</td></tr></table>
<body>
</html>
```

Could you please review the code and suggest how can I achieve it? Also, Any suggestions in code improvements are welcome.

Comment: All of this needs to be done in javascript, not ampscript - ampscript is processed server side and can’t do things like displaying popus or in any way interacting with dom

Comment: How to do the same in JS if its supported only SSJS?

Comment: That is a misunderstanding - You can use frontend / client-side / "normal" javascript on cloudpages. Apart from that, this will indeed be the wrong place to get js support.